# How to select all records in Table A that are not referenced for specific record in Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select all data belonging to playlisticons table except for data that user Tom also have in playlist table.

Edit: I also have other users in the playlist table and hence I only want to return all playlisticons except for those that user Tom already have.

My code looks something like this:

```
    
SELECT 
playlisticons.name
,playlisticons.link 
FROM 
playlisticons 
LEFT JOIN playlist ON 
 playlisticons.name != playlist.icon WHERE playlist.userFK = 'Tom';
```

playlisticons.name and playlist.icon shares the same value
playlisticons:

| name | link |
| --- | --- |
| Heart | link1 |
| Bookmark | link2 |
| Like | link3 |

playlist:

| playlistID | name | userFK | icon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Favourite | Tom | Heart |
| 2 | Watchlist | Tom | Bookmark |

Current output:

| name | link |
| --- | --- |
| Heart | link1 |
| Bookmark | link2 |
| Like | link3 |
| Like | link3 |

Expected output:

| name | link |
| --- | --- |
| Like | link3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    playlisticons.name,
    playlisticons.link
FROM playlisticons
WHERE
    playlisticons.name NOT IN (
        SELECT
            icon
        FROM playlist
        WHERE userfk = 'Tom'
    )
;
```

Comment: I've tried that but the sql doesnt return any values. Thanks for helping tho

Comment: @Armistice please try my updated answer. I was copied from your SQL and there are something wrong

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Technically that does work but only if there is only 1 user. However, I have multiple users and wants to return all data from playlisticon that playlist.userFK does not have

Comment: Why is it not working? It should work. Please update your questions to provide more information or data

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all `playlisticons` that nobody used it at all? Or all `playlisticons` that are not used by each user?

Comment: all playlisticons not used by by the user. In this case it is tom

Comment: So it is all playlisticons not used by `a specific user`

Comment: Yeah, not used by a specific user

Comment: Thanks alot. Been trying to solve this for the past day

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, LINK FROM PLAYGROUND.PLAYLISTICONS 
LEFT JOIN PLAYGROUND.PLAYLIST ON PLAYLISTICONS.name = PLAYLIST.ICON 
WHERE PLAYGROUND.PLAYLIST.USERFK IS NULL;
```